# How to get anonymous guest link for "Image" in Sharepoint 2010 Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, picture-library

i am trying to send email to gmail user , i am using images from picture library.
but gmail user unable to see this images.
is that possible to use image guest url ..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Anonymous links to those images so that the use doesn't need login to view those images by following below steps:

**1.** Go to the picture library and select the image for which you want to create a link.

**2.** Click on "Shared With" from the context menu of Item or from the Files tab of ribbon menu.

**3.** Click on "Get a Link" in the dialog box and select "View link - no sign-in required" from the drop down and wait for a few seconds. The textbox below the drop-down will have the link that you can use in the workflow email step.

**Note:** If you are creating the image links dynamically in workflow, this will not be applicable.

Here is a sample image which is in o365 site:

[image]